# Jmeter test MyISAM / InnoDB

Tags: mysql, jmeter, innodb, myisam

I have written Jmeter test for etesting platform. This platform has 7 tables. By default all of them are `MyISAM`. Since this platforms performance wasn't satisfying I decided to try converting all of them to `InnoDB` and making necessary changes to *my.cnf*.

I've asked already about my mysql config file, and with some help from stackoverflow users came to conclusion that it's good enough. 
Server has 4 Cores, 6 GB of RAM.

Now about jmeter test. I ran it with 100 threads and ramp-up-period of 60.

Test performed under `MyISAM`:

[image: MyISAM]

Test performed under `InnoDB`:

[image: InnoDB]

Here's some info about those errors from `Jmeter`:

```
Thread Name: etestas.nec.lt 1-43
Sample Start: 2014-03-13 14:01:04 EET
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1383
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1383
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 451: http://..../taooradev/taoQtiTest/TestRunner/moveForward?QtiTestDefinition=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A83%2Ftaooradev%2Ftao_perf26.rdf%23i13946258434723150&QtiTestCompilation=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A83%2Ftaooradev%2Ftao_perf26.rdf%23i13946278408675414-%7Chttp%3A%2F%2F...%3A83%2Ftaooradev%2Ftao_perf26.rdf%23i13946278401451415%2B&standalone=true&serviceCallId=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A83%2Ftaooradev%2Ftao_perf26.rdf%23${calid2}

Response headers:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

I don't really think if those benchmarks matter here, since I'm asking if any of you has some experience with MySQL (at least more than me) and can tell what could possible cause those errors while using `InnoDB`. I don't really expect to get an answer, just maybe some thoughts or ideas where to look for it.

EDIT: I was thinking, maybe this has to something with table/row level locking. Maybe since Innodb has row level locking and MyISAM table level, there might occur some errors, if platform wasn't written with the idea of row level locking. That would complicate things greatly for me.

EDIT: calid2: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this seems to be an error in your request, because `${calid2}` is probably not-expanded variable and symbols `$ { }` are not allowed in URI's

Comment: Do you use calid2 later in request parameters? It seems that you have issue with variable substitution and get **${calid2}** in request instead of it's value.

Comment: Variable itself has nothing to with it. I've added Redis DB to this platform, so that all data would go to Redis, while stable data, that doesn't change would stay with InnoDB Mysql table. That way, table is hardly increasing and I get 0% errors.